# Change Property Name at return time in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web API 2 with EF 6 DB first approach. While fetching an entity, I want to change the property name.

For example: I have an **`Employee`** entity, and one of the properties is called `EmployeeJoiningDate`, same as the database column name.

While getting `context.Employee`, I want to "rename" `EmployeeJoiningDateproperty` as `EmpJd` (during serialization).

Is there any way to achieve this without creating another class and map to that new class? Is there any attribute?

Comment: I used this attribute in edmx tt class (Employee.cs)
 `[Column("EmployeeJoiningDateproperty ")]
public string EmpJd {get;set;}`

but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Database Field is called "EmployeeJoiningDate" but you want the property in your entity to be EmpJd:

```
[Column("EmployeeJoiningDate")]
public string EmpJd { get; set; }
```

Make note that the name in the Column attribute needs to match what is in the table, no extra spaces etc.

This assumes that the data type in the table is also an NVarchar type. If the data type in the data table is a DateTime then I'd recommend a different approach...

```
public DateTime EmployeeJoiningDate { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string EmpJd
{
  get { return EmployeeJoiningDate.ToString(); } // Optionally add format string.
  set 
  {
    DateTime result;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(value, out result))
      throw new ArgumentException("The provided EmpJd was not recognized as a date.");
    EmployeeJoiningDate = result;
  }
}
```

This gives you an EmpJd field that you can use with your code. An important detail is that in this case if you want to use Linq etc. against your entity, use the EmployeeJoiningDate property in the Linq expressions. EF will *not* resolve EmpJd to the EmployeeJoiningDate.
If you only want to display the date as a string you can omit the Setter for the EmpJd property.